$a_n=(n+a_{n+1})^{1/2}$. Closed form for $a_n$?
Given the sequence $a_n=(n+a_{n+1})^{1/2}$, I am looking for clues on how to find the explicit expression $a_n=f(n)$. I'm not troubled about proof of its convergence; just about calculating its explicit expression as a sole function of $n$. I don't seem to be able to use Ramanujan's treatment, $x+n+a= ...$, as the $(x+n)(...)^{1/2}$ term eliminates my ability to keep the nested radicals multiplied by a cool 1 coefficient. Other standard tools in my math toolbox don't seem to serve me. I'm an engineer PhD, not a math professional, so I may be missing something really obvious to a more specialized mind like yours. Please, help with clues. Of course I am mainly interested in evaluating $n=1$.
Note: Someone edited my original question's title and I think it was an improvement. Just need to point out that
$a_1=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{4+...}}}}$ with $a_0=\sqrt{a_1}$.

Why not change it to $a_n=..$ by squaring? Squaring gives you $_1=_0^2 start there $

Squaring gives you $a_1=a_0^2 $ start there .

What do you mean by $a_n = f(n)$? Is $f(n)$ any arbitary function?

Are the brackets simple parenthesis or the floor function ?

@trula , thank you. Yes, I tried that. Just don't see it. Will keep on trying. I appreciate the clue.

@Kraken , thank you. $F(n)$ is the closed form of $a_n$ as a function of $n$.

@zwim , thank you. I edited the expressions to include round parenthesis, for clarification. Thank you.

So you basically want to find solve your recurrence, correct?

@Kraken yes you got it

Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147217/asymptotic-behavior-of-the-sequence-u-n-u-n-12-n

This is not a "nested radical sum".

I believe for $a_1=1$ your sequence is given by OEIS Entry A086851 which gives an approximation but not a closed form. For $a_1=2$ see OEIS Entry A198959. Also, see this related MSO question.

I don't understand the presentation of the recursion. Normally you would give a clear explicit value for $a_0$ or $a_1$, and then write $a_n$ in terms of the previous term $a_{n-1}$, not in terms of the next term $a_{n+1}$. But you've defined $a_1$ using $\cdots$, so already you mean for $a_1$ to be the limit of some sequence, and it's not clear what that sequence is. Is $a_1$ the limit of ${\sqrt{1},\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}},\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}},\ldots}$?

@2'59'2 , see the link in my own answer. I $defined$ $a_n$ with a recursion, which is all I have. I $expanded$ $a_1$ with the only way I can see to expand it. $a_n=(n+a_{n+1})^{1/2}$, then $a_1=\sqrt{1+a_2}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+a_3}}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+a_4}}}$ and so on. I understand the presentation of the case may be unfamiliar to some people. I noticed it for the first time in Ramanujan's works some years ago. I am only an amateur. And yes, your proposed limit will do.

@StevenClark , thank you.

I am not able to comment, I apologize for giving this as an answer.
I don't believe there is a closed form. You can find the constant for computing the asymptotic behavior on OEIS, see here. Of course these constants are dependent on $a_0$, but they can be computed in general. The approximation this gives is not good for small $n$ (say $n<5$), but as $n$ increases it is very accurate, since the linear term has a negligible contribution. The method by which this constant is determined is touched on in the link below as well.
As a side-note, if $n$ is a constant (unrelated to the to the subscripts of $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$), then there is a closed form when this constant satisfies certain conditions. In particular, if $n = 1$ is constant, a closed form given in equation (4) here. Although again, I don't think this was the subject of your question.

thank you. I think you got what my intention is. Yes, $n$ is the independent variable of the $a_n$ series. Somehow it is a relief that an expert thinks my problem has no closed form, since I had a difficult time trying to see a way thru the answer. I got kind suggestions from other members noticing that $a_0=(a_1)^{1/2}$ which is true but I could not take advantage of. Any further ideas are appreciated.

@RandallMarinEsquivel $a_1\ne(a_0)^{1/2}$. $a_{n+1}=a_n^2-n$, so $a_1=a_0^2$.

@AnneBauval thank you

Answer: "No closed-form expression is known for this constant (Finch 2003, p. 8; S. Plouffe, pers. comm., Aug. 29, 2008)". So, I tried to ride an untamed one.
https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NestedRadicalConstant.html
